# Mostrar valores que no existen al contar y agrupar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas Gente vengo con un problema que me esta dando dolores de cabeza para hacer con SQL Server, en mi BD tengo varios campos pero solo me interesan 2 **tipoincidencia** y **fechaactualizacion** entonces lo que necesito hacer es contar cuantos **tipoincidencia** se hicieron por **fechaactualizacion** sea 0 o que realmente haya un valor al hacerlo con esta query

```
select tipodeincidencia , count (tipodeincidencia)'cantidad',fechaactualizacion from proyectos group by tipodeincidencia, fechaactualizacion
```

obtengo lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito obtener algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo general se crean tablas de dimensiones, en este caso tus días del año (o series) y se hace una reunión por la izquierda para que obtengas cero cuando no hay ocurrencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente ya lo pude solucionar dejo el script

```
    ;WITH Fechas AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT fechaactualizacion 
    FROM proyectos),
TiposIncidencia AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT tipodeincidencia 
    FROM proyectos
),
Datos AS (
    SELECT F.fechaactualizacion,
           I.tipodeincidencia,
           CASE 
            WHEN p.TipodeIncidencia IS NULL
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END AS 'cantidad'
           FROM Fechas F
           CROSS JOIN TiposIncidencia I
           LEFT JOIN proyectos P
                ON P.fechaactualizacion = F.fechaactualizacion
                AND P.tipodeincidencia = I.tipodeincidencia
)
SELECT fechaactualizacion
        ,TipodeIncidencia
        ,SUM(cantidad) Cantidad
FROM Datos
GROUP BY fechaactualizacion, TipodeIncidencia
ORDER BY fechaactualizacion, TipodeIncidencia
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es un producto cartesiano entre toda posible fecha y todo tipo de incidencia, con esto relacionamos luego a `proyectos` para contar finalmente las cantidades:

```
SELECT F.fechaactualizacion,
       I.tipodeincidencia,
       ISNULL(count(P.tipodeincidencia),0) as 'cantidad'
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fechaactualizacion FROM proyectos) F
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tipodeincidencia FROM proyectos) I
       LEFT JOIN proyectos P
            ON P.fechaactualizacion = F.fechaactualizacion
            AND P.tipodeincidencia = I.tipodeincidencia
       GROUP BY F.fechaactualizacion,
                I.tipodeincidencia
       ORDER BY F.fechaactualizacion,
                I.tipodeincidencia
```

Esto muy posiblemente no sea la forma ideal ya que tal vez hay un costo importante en obtener todas las posibles fechas y todos los tipos de incidente (el `DISTINCT`). La alternativa es manejar esta información en tablas aparte, una para los tipo de inicidentes y otra para las fechas.

Comment: Corri la Query y me figuran en el count un 1 cuando tal vez debe figurar un 0 
dejo la imagen de la ejecucion en el detalle de la pregunta @patricio

Comment: @federicovazquez: Ahi lo corregí, debería contar bien ahora.